# SUM function is not working in MYSQL store procedure?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

Whenever run the store  procedure its return the same output 106.
It's sum of all data of number1 column. 
Below the my sample code.
I hope it will help you.
Please correct me if i have any error.

**Store Procedure :**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE raw_data(IN user_id INT(10),IN p_id INT(10))
BEGIN
    SELECT SUM(number1) AS result FROM raw_data WHERE user_id=user_id AND p_id=p_id; 
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Table Format :**

```
       id name    number1     number2       user_id    p_id
        1   a       10          20              1       49
        2   b       12          12              1       49
        3   c       20          30              2       48
        4   d       22          22              2       48
        5   c       20          30              2       48
        6   d       22          22              2       49
```

**Input :**

```
CALL raw_data(1, 49);
```

**Output :**

```
result
106
```

Note : Output(106) is same if any input is given.
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 3):

Your parameters are confused with the column names.  Always prepend them with something to distinguish them:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE raw_data(IN in_user_id INT(10), IN in_p_id INT(10))
BEGIN
    SELECT SUM(rd.number1) AS result
    FROM raw_data rd
    WHERE rd.user_id = in_user_id AND rd.p_id = in_p_id; 
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

In your `where` statement, the column in the table (`user_id`) is being compared to the column in the table (`user_id)`.  The best solution is to name the parameters of the stored procedure so they will not match columns in the table.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Renaming the input variables solved an issue for me where a sum was not totalling.